# Bash for-loop not continuing even when body is launched in background subshell (works in zsh)

Tags: bash, for-loop, parallel-processing, subshell

When I run the following script in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

names=("ALL" "no_C" "no_R" "no_Q")

for name in $names; do
    export name=$name
    mkdir -p $name
    ( echo 'selection' 'System' | gmx cluster -f ${name}_protein_only.trr -s ${name}_protein_only.pdb -n ${name}_index.ndx -g ${name}/cluster.log -cutoff 0.2 -fit -method gromos -o ${name}/cluster.output -dist ${name}/rmsd-dist.xvg -av -cl ${name}/clusters.pdb ) &
done
wait
```

The for loop won't loop until the subshell has completed, even though I've put it into the background with '&'. If I run this same script in zsh, it runs as expected (4 parallel tasks). Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a different notation for all the elements of an array in Bash (see [Arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays) and [Shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)):

```
for name in "${name[@]}"; do
```

When you specify `$name` and `name` is an array, Bash treats it as `${name[0]}`.

I used this variant on your code to demonstrate:

```
#!/bin/bash

names=("ALL" "no_C" "no_R" "no_Q")

for name in "${names[@]}"
do
    export name=$name
    mkdir -p $name
    ( echo $name 'selection' 'System' | sed s/s/z/g; sleep 3 ) &
done
wait
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) [wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34833959/15168) is correct in terms of the definition of a Bash array and how to loop through it.

But, if you wanted to define `names` as a series of strings like this:

```
names="ALL no_C no_R no_Q"
```

Then you could still loop through it using:

```
for name in $names; do
  .... do something with name
done
```

Comment: That is another way of dealing with the problem.  It would not be a good idea if any of the names currently in the array themselves contained spaces.  At that point, an array is _definitely_ the correct way to go.